# Can the periodicity in k-space of the electronic band structure be understood as a result of aliasing?

Tags: electrons, solid-state-physics, crystals, phonons, signal-processing

### Discrete sampling in the case of phonons

In the case of phonons in periodic solids, the picture is quite intuitive. The motion of the atoms in the lattice is described as a continuous wave (amplitude as a function of position and time). However, since it only makes sense to define an amplitude at the position of the atoms, a discrete sampling of the continuous wave is made, leading to ambiguity in the wavelength of the oscillation. This is because waves of different wavelengths can be used to describe the same set of samples (see figure). This aliasing effect thus naturally leads to the concept of Brillouin zones for phonons.

[image: Aliasing: a discrete set of samples can be described by waves of different wavelengths]

---

### Applicability to electrons

To what extent can the periodicity of the electronic band structure be understood using the same picture? In the case of electrons, the wave under consideration is their quantum wavefunction. The difference with the phonon wave is that it is not only the value of the wavefunction at the atomic positions that is relevant: the wavefunction is equally real in between the atoms. Thus, it is not clear to me whether the same argument of discrete sampling can be applied.

Comment: I think you are pushing the analogy way too far. While the atoms are discrete, the forces between them are continuous in position. A phonon is clearly a wave disturbance propagating through the lattice, and must be explained using the same Bloch restrictions as the electronic wave functions.

Comment: Also, in principle, shouldn't a quantum description of the lattice have a wave function also for the atoms, such that they have a probability to occupy positions between lattice points?

Answer (score 1):

I think the aliasing argument makes perfect sense when applied to phonons. I've seen it applied in solid state physics textbooks numerous times for the phonon case (See The Oxford Solid State Basics, 1st Edition, Page 80 for example). As for periodicity of electronic k-space, I think it's perfectly reasonable to extend the argument here as well.